# Initialize an array with unique numbers per column

Tags: .net, f#

Using F#, I'd like to generate a 2D array which represent a Bingo card. The Bingo card must have unique number per column. Below is what I have right now, this generate a card with the proper dimension and range of number depending on the column, but this doesn't resolve the uniqueness part.

```
let generateCard =
    let randNumberGen = new Random()
    Array2D.init 5 5 (fun i j -> randNumberGen.Next((i * 15) + 1, ((i + 1) * 15 + 1)))
```

I am not looking for an imperative way to do this. I could easily do that in C#, but I am trying hard to find better ways to accomplish this using functional/F# style.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to solve the problem. The structure of the code is different than in your version - I'm generating an array of arrays (rows) and then convert this to 2D array using `array2D`. Values in each row are generated using `uniqueNumbers` function that generates a sequence of unique numbers using the given random number generator (a function).

To generate unique numbers, we use a recursive loop and keep a set of `generated` numbers. When we generate a new number, we first check that the number is not in the generated set (if it is, we try another one). Note that this gets slower if you require larger number of unique numbers (but this is probably not an issue in this example):

```
let uniqueNumbers generator =
  let rec loop generated = seq {
    let n = generator()
    if Set.contains n generated then
      yield! loop generated 
    else
      yield n
      yield! loop (Set.add n generated) }
  loop Set.empty
```

Now we can generate a card by iterating over row indices 0 to 4 and we generate a row with unique numbers (and we take 5 unique numbers to build each row):

```
let generateCard =
  let randNumberGen = new Random()
  [ for i in 0 .. 4 ->
      uniqueNumbers (fun () -> randNumberGen.Next((i * 15) + 1, ((i + 1) * 15 + 1)))
      |> Seq.take 5 ]
  |> array2D
```

Comment: For `uniqueNumbers` why not just use `Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> generator()) |> Seq.distinct`?

Comment: @Daniel That looks like a simpler way to get the same behaviour (I completely forgot about `Seq.distinct`)!

Comment: Could you also use the random number as an index into unused numbers?  I would imagine this would be more performant than continuously generating new random numbers until you found one that wasn't used.

Comment: @mydogisbox Yes, that would be more efficient if you had a lot of collisions (but you'd need more memory to store the numbers). In this specific case, the number of collisions is pretty small, though...

Answer (score 1):

Unique columns and rows.

```
open System;
let r = new Random();
let generator n = fun (_) -> r.Next() % n

let uniqueColumns cols g =
   let rec fn  list =
       let row = Seq.take cols (Seq.distinct g) |> Seq.toList
       let anyEqual a b = Seq.zip a b |> Seq.exists (fun (a,b)->a=b)
       seq {
       if Set.exists (anyEqual row) list then
           yield! fn  list
       else
           yield row
           yield! fn  (Set.add row list)
       }
   fn Set.empty
;;

let g = Seq.initInfinite (generator 10)
uniqueColumns 5 g
|> Seq.take 4 
|> Seq.toList
```

outputs

```
[[6; 3; 7; 4; 8]; 
 [7; 6; 8; 9; 5]; 
 [0; 7; 1; 3; 4];
 [5; 4; 3; 7; 0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A variant on the above answer by factoring out some predicates

```
open System;

let r = new Random();
let generator n = fun (_) -> r.Next() % n

// generic function for detecting distinctness via Predicate
let rec distinctBy pred ss =
    let set = ref Set.empty
    seq {
        for s in ss do
          if Set.contains s set.Value |> not then
            yield s
            set.Value <- Set.add s set.Value                       
      };;

// A generator for columns
let newRow cols = fun (_) -> 
    Seq.initInfinite (generator 10) 
    |> Seq.take cols 
    |> Seq.toList

let anyEqual a b = Seq.zip a b |> Seq.exists (fun (a,b)->a=b)

// A Generator for rows
Seq.initInfinite (newRow 4)
  |> distinctBy anyEqual
  |> Seq.take 5 
  |> Seq.toList;;
```

outputs

```
[[6; 3; 7; 4; 8]; 
 [7; 6; 8; 9; 5]; 
 [0; 7; 1; 3; 4];
 [5; 4; 3; 7; 0]]
```

Comment: Not so happy about the mutable in distinct by though! :(